# Why does go have := short assignments inside functions?

Tags: go

I don't quite understand the specific purpose of short assignments,

why do this:

```
x:= 10
```

when this is also possible:

```
var x = 10
```

Is there any specific use case where short assignments are more convenient
Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
if x, err := fn(); err != nil {
    // do something
}
```

In the above case, the variables are confined within the if statement. If you try to access `err` outside of the if statement, it won't be available. Likewise for `x`. There's various cases where maintaining scope like this might be useful, but I'd say the use of `:=` is for given styles like the above with `if`, `switch`, `for`.

For some additional background, `var` also allows grouping, much like using `import`.

```
var (
    y = 1
    z = 2
)
```

which pushes the use-cases for `var` vs `:=` further apart.

Answer (score 3):

**Example 1:**

```
var age int = 30
```

**Example 2:**

```
var age = 30
```

**Example 3:**

```
age := 30
```

All of the examples above are the same. **Example 2** and **Example 3** simply '**infer**' the type.  It's also a type of shorthand.   Below is an excerpt from a public domain - creative commons pdf, **"An Introduction To Programming In GO", by Caleb Doxsey**

'Since creating a new variable with a starting value is so common Go also supports a shorter statement:

```
x := "Hello World"
```

Notice the **`:`** before the **`=`** and that no type was specified.  The type is not necessary because the Go compiler is able to infer the type based on the **literal value** you assign the variable. (Since you are assigning a string
literal, x is given the type string)

The compiler can also do inference with the var statement:

```
var x = "Hello World"
```

The same thing works for other types:

```
x := 5
fmt.Println(x)
```

Generally you should use this shorter form **whenever** possible.'

Comment: I appreciate the quote, but the book is not in the public domain.

Comment: My bad, Caleb.  I would like to remove the statement and make the correction to my post, but then your reply would be non-nonsensical.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that `:=` mainly exists as a convenient syntax for receiving the results of function calls, where one often desires to reuse an existing variable, while declaring a new one:

```
x, err := func1()
if err != nil {
    fmt.Fatal(err)
}
y, err := func2()
if err != nil {
    fmt.Fatal(err)
}
```

The above code compiles because `:=` allows existing variables to be listed, as long as *at least one* new variable is created. Try replacing `y, err :=` with `var y, err =` and you will find it does not compile.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason in that case, they are equivalent.

It makes sense when you have this

```
var i int
i = 0
```

So you can be more concise and infer the type with

```
i := 0
```

But otherwise they're exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
x := fn()
```

that will make `x` the same type as the return type of the function `fn`.  If you refactor your code and the return type of `fn` changes, `x`'s type will be changed for free.

...and it's less typing.

Comment: The same is true of `var x = fn()`. *(Not the "less typing" part of course.)*

Comment: _Typing_ here was very ambiguous:
1. Keyboard strokes? or
2. Use of types?

Comment: that's the joke